# AssertionError: If capturable=False, state_steps should not be CUDA tensors

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I get this error while loading model weights of a previous epoch on Google colab. I'm using PyTorch version 1.12.0. I can't downgrade to a lower version as there are external libraries that Im using that require Pytorch 1.12.0

Thanks!

Comment: According to latest update, this issue is fixed if you update to torch [1.12.1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/80809#issuecomment-1175211598)

Answer (score 2):

It seems related to a newly introduced parameter (capturable) for the `Adam` and `AdamW` optimizers. Currently two workarounds:

1. forcing capturable = True after loading the checkpoint `optim.param_groups[0]['capturable'] = True`. This seems to slow down the model training by approx. 10% (YMMV depending on the setup).
2. Reverting PyTorch back to previous versions (could be 1.11.0).

Source: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/80809#issuecomment-1173481031

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PyTorch 1.12.0 with Cuda binaries 11.6/11.7 then on your shell or command prompt, paste the following;

```
pip install torch==1.12.1+cu116 torchvision==0.13.1+cu116 torchaudio==0.12.1 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

The Adam Optimizer regression was removed in the updated torch version

**Edit**
There's a new torch version use this to install it

```
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me which Optimizer you are using. I have encountered this with AdamW optimizer. You can avoid it by loading optimizer with the load_state_dict and then mapping it to cpu explicitly using `.cpu()` function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).